# How to send structure from a C application to an Java Application with UDP

Tags: java, c, serialization, udp, structure

I actually want to send a structure over UDP from a C application to a java application.

The struct looking like that :

```
typedef struct {
type1 liste1;
type2 liste2;
type3 liste3;
type4 liste4;
}liste;
```

And type1,2,3,4 are also structure which include themselves others structures too.

For now, I just send the structure like that (liste is my structure) :

```
sendto(socketOut, &(liste), sizeof(liste), 0, (SOCKADDR *) &(recvAddrAck),sizeof(recvAddrAck));
```

And I get the UDP like that on the java application :

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
byte[] buf = new byte[1500];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
while (true) {
socket.receive(packet);
data = packet.getData();
}
```

So, my question is, how to decode data ? I'm quite a newbe with UDP protocols, but I've made some research with my friend Google, and I found some things like htons/htonl/... for the C side, and ByteArrayInputStream/DataInputStream ... for the java side.
But I don't really understand how and when I have to use this things, especially for the java side.

Hoping my question is understandable

Thanks

Comment: i think before you send your struct to java, you can convert it to a text format like **liste1;liste2;liste3;liste4**. Then your java application will get a raw text value then split values of your struct and make it a java class.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to serialize in some way. Either manually, via some text format or XML, or if you want something more robust, look into ASN.1 / BER libraries on both sides.

Comment: I've looked into ASN.1 / BER libraries, but I don't know if it's just the first approch, but it's look difficult to use

Comment: I agree, it's complicated, but it's a hard thing to do in a generalized way. Creating an export/import format specific to your structure would be easier, and XML is an ok format for that, because it's self-documenting and easily understandable.

Comment: I disagree about ASN.1 being difficult to use.  Take a look at http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/introduction.html (ASN.1 Made Simple).  The right ASN.1 tool can make your task easy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand, but did you take a look at DatagramPacket ?

Something like

```
DatagramPacket answerPacket = null;
  try { 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[REC_BUFFER_SIZE];
    answerPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, REC_BUFFER_SIZE);
    yourSocket.receive(answerPacket);
    log.debug("Received UDP Packet from " + answerPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
  } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    log.debug("No Answer - Connection to DatagramSocket timed out");
  }

if (answerPacket != null && answerPacket.getLength() != 0) {
    String result = new String(answerPacket.getData());
    result = result.trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespaces...
}
```

might do what you need, but it means the usage of a custom format.

Comment: This is what I use, and it works if I send for example `char * tmp = "hello";` I will receive hello on the java side, but with complicated structure, I don't really know how to proceed ...

Comment: Figure out a way to encode your structure, for example, using XML or a delimited list of fields.

Comment: I would not choose xml, but something simpler, | separated values, or JSON like syntax, something not too complicated on the C side

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI, I think, your solution would be the simpliest for me, but how to calculate the proper size of the buffer which will be send over UDP ? I can't find, how to calculate it dynamicly ...

Comment: For sending, it's pretty straightforward :
     byte[] msgByte = message.getBytes();
     packetToSend = new DatagramPacket(msgByte, msgByte.length, ....

Comment: Yes, but sending is on the C application. I succeed to send my structure by doing this : FIRST : thanks to cJSON I was able to create the Json format of my structures, then I send over UDP two packets, the first one indicate the size of the second packet and on the second packet, the formated json structure. THEN on the java side, I receive the two packets, the first one fixing the size of the second one, then with Gson I was able to get back my structure by creating the Java class of my structure. Hoping this explication is understable and helpfull for next ones.